# TImageList GetHandle Returning Integer Greater Than MaxInt

Tags: windows, delphi, bitmap, vcl

I am in the process of converting a Delphi XE8 project to Delphi 11.2. In the project, I am creating a `TImageList` at runtime, and loading in bitmaps from a `.res` file.

When building and running this project in XE8, I have no issues. However, when I build and run in Delphi 11.2, I get the following debugger exception when I try to get the `TImageList.Handle`:

> Project Project1.exe raised exception class ERangeError with message 'Range check error'

I believe this is because the value that is being returned is greater than the max integer.

```pascal
bitmap := Tbitmap.Create;

ImageList := TImageList.Create(Self);
ImageList.Masked := True;
ImageList.ShareImages := False;
ImageList.Width := 10;
ImageList.Height := 10;

bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'bitmap1'); 
ImageList.AddMasked(bitmap, clWhite);

bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'bitmap2'); 
ImageList.AddMasked(bitmap, clWhite);

bitmap.Free;

// Will result in handle integer greater than maxint
ImageList.Handle;
```

I've tried replacing `TImageList` with a `TVirtualImage` list as well, but I still get the same error.

Why would this be happening?

Comment: Because ImageList.Handle is HImageList -> THandle -> NativeUInt, so it is unsigned integer.

Comment: i assume, this is `HIMAGELIST` - what is `ImageList_Create` return. but this is pointer (to some object) and it of course can be 8 bytes on 64 bit, not fit to 4 bytes

Comment: Thank you. It's not the GetHandle method that's throwing the exception. The value is passed to another function that wants a signed 32-bit int. Is there a reason for the difference from Delphi XE8 and 11.2 (smaller int to bigger int)?

Comment: "*The value is passed to another function that wants a signed 32-bit int*" - that is a mistake. `TImageList.Handle` returns a `THandle` not an integer. The function is wrong, it needs to be updated to take the proper type in the first place.